# Multiple .attr('value')

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am a little new to jQuery but I was wondering if there was a way to add multiple values to this:

`if ($(this).find(":selected").attr('value') == "196")`

Instead of having just "196" can I have an array of possible values?

Comment: What is this? I'm guessing a `<selec>` with `<option>`'s?...

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery: Adding two attributes via the .attr(); method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13014317/jquery-adding-two-attributes-via-the-attr-method)

Comment: You can check if the value is contained in an array of values, sure, by writing JavaScript.

Comment: Try `if($.inArray($(this).find(":selected").attr('value'), [196, 200, 105]) > -1)`.

Comment: jQuery getter methods (such as `.attr("attributeName")`) only return the value of the first item in the collection. you're probably better off using .filter and inArray if it's possible for more than one to be selected.

Comment: It is a select with options yes. Rocket Hazmat: that solution worked perfectly. My followup question is will it take a variable that contains all the values I wish to use?

Comment: I figured it out. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You want to find out if the value of the selected input is one of several possibilities, correct? You can create an array of possibilities and use `indexOf` to see if your value matches any of them.

```
var selectedValue = $(this).find(':selected').attr('value'),
    possibilities = [196, 666, 907];

selectedValue = +selectedValue; // coerce the value to a number

if(possibilities.indexOf(selectedValue) !== -1) {
    // Your selected value matches one of the possibilities
} else {
    // Your selected value does not match any of the possiblities
}
```