# How to add multiple attributes with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes, attr

I followed all the answers on this post [jQuery: Adding two attributes via the .attr(); method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13014317/jquery-adding-two-attributes-via-the-attr-method) and none of them work for multiple attributes, only single attribute work.

E.g.

```
$("img").attr({
data-aos: "fade-down",
data-aos-duration: "600"
});
```

Does not work. But single attribute does work:

```
$("img").attr("data-aos", "fade-down");
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bwj5uex0/3/
You can test on JSFiddle with your browser's built-in dev tools after CTRL+Enter.

Comment: As you can see from the syntax highlighting in the Fiddle, the `-` character is being interpreted as the subtraction operator, so you have a syntax error. You instead need to wrap the attribute names in quotes: https://jsfiddle.net/bwj5uex0/4/. Voting to close as a typo

Comment: Did you read beyond the accepted answer?  You said "all" answers, yet there it is:  `$(myObj).attr({"data-test-1": num1, "data-test-2": num2});`

Comment: @freedomn-m it's not working, because `num1 num2` not quoted as answered below in this question.

Comment: @freedomn-m Apparently this solution works if it's all in one line, if you break into new lines values and attributes both must be in quotes.

Comment: "values and attributes must be in quotes" - not if you're using a variable, but yes if it's a string.  Newlines / spaces have no impact (other than in a rare case which doesn't count here).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just quote the names:

```
$("img").attr({
    "data-aos": "fade-down",
    "data-aos-duration": "600"
});
```

This is a standard feature of JavaScript object initializers, and works with jQuery's `attr`. The property names can be literals (`foo:`), string literals (`"foo":` or `'foo'`:), numeric literals (`1:`) (they get converted to string), or (in ES2015 onward) computed names using `[]` notation.

Live Example (right-click the image and choose Inspect / Inspect Element to see the attributes):

```js
$("img").attr({
    "data-aos": "fade-down",
    "data-aos-duration": "600"
});
```

```html
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200/44F/DDD?text=hi+there">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You may get people suggesting you use [`data`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) for this instead of [`attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/). Many people have a misunderstanding, thinking `data` is an accessor for `data-*` attributes. It isn't; [details here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8707226/jquery-data-does-not-work-but-attr-does/45149219#45149219).

Answer (score -2):

Alternatively, you can use the camelCase style for keys declaration

```
$("img").attr({
    dataAos:"fade-down",
    dataAosDuration:"600"
})
```

Comment: Not for custom `data-*` properties. The above will put `dataaos="fade-down"` on the element, not `data-aos="fade-down"`.