# Adding more than one attribute when using append in dropdown - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add more than one attr() value when using append in a dropdown in jQuery.

This is working fine:

```
$('#twostages').append($('<option/>').attr("value", option.stage).text(option.stage));
```

And I can access the value using:

```
document.getElementById("twostages").value
```

However, when I try this code:

```
$('#twostages').append($('<option/>').attr({ "value": option.stage, "matone": option.matone }).text(option.stage));
```

I am not able to retrieve the `value` or `matone` using the `document.getElementById("twostages").value` or `document.getElementById("twostages").matone`

I got the idea of the above code from this topic: [jQuery: Adding two attributes via the .attr(); method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13014317/jquery-adding-two-attributes-via-the-attr-method)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: `matone` is not a default property and hens you can not access directly. You can use jquery `.attr()` in same way to get value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`matone` is a property added on options.So you can't access it directly.

you need to check first the selected option and then get it's corresponding `matone` value using `.attr()`

***Working snippet:-***

```js
$('#twostages').append($('<option/>').attr({ "value":"stage1", "matone": "mymetion" }).text("stage1"));

console.log($('#twostages').val());
console.log($('#twostages').find(':selected').attr('matone'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="twostages">

</select>
```

***Reference:-***

[.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

[:selected](https://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/)

***Note:-*** Standered practice is to use [data-attributes](https://api.jquery.com/data/) for custom attributes

Comment: @HamzaAhmad  glad to help you